# get content of a specific svn revision in subclipse plugin

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, revision

my eclipse plugin is comparing a specific revision of svn with the same revision that was patched by another user.
i want to retrieve the content of a specific revision to my plugin, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to load the content of a specific version to your editor, you can do so by selecting in the context menu of the editor "Replace with" and then "Revision".

Comment: thanks for your comment,
to be more precise my plugin is used to review a diff file that was created by another developer, which mean it is going over a list of files each one of them in a specific revision. i want to create the content of the file as it was created by the developer. in order to do that i need to have the content of the revision of the file that the developer was started from, apply the patch diff on this revision and compare there content. this file is not necessarily managed by my workspace.